# Laravel force unique role validation fail in form request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

My controller is as below:

```
public function update(PermissionFormRequest $request,$id)
{
    $permissionUpdated = $this->permission->update($request,$id);
    if($permissionUpdated){
        //return $permissionUpdated;
        return 'updated';
    }
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Can not update ticket']);    
}
```

Form request code is:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' =>'required|unique:permissions,name,'.$this->id,
    ];
}
```

When trying to update with **same id**, an error is thrown as:

> {"name":["The name has already been taken."]}

Comment: Why you not use `'name' =>'required|unique:permissions,name,'.$id,` I think you didn't get `$this->id`

Comment: @HirenGohel i already tried but $id says undefined variable id.

Comment: So `$this->id` gave you `id`??

Comment: Try with this: `$request->input('id')`

Comment: Is it worked???

Comment: @HirenGohel no bro still not worked.

Comment: You need to pass `$id` in rules,then you get `id`. Like: `public function rules($id)` and use `'name' =>'required|unique:permissions,name,'.$id,` Let me know if this works!

Comment: why do you need `name` and  `id` to be unique in update request ?

Comment: @jaysingkar only name should unique but when updating i want to force unique for id of name.

Comment: can you post your method here ? What I think is, your `$id` field is not getting the correct id. Could you `dd($this->id)` once and check if the id filed is there

Comment: @jaysingkar i got $request variable but $id is null.

Comment: As I understand ,  you are passing id to your controller via route parameter and not by request. So, you can add a hidden field to your form with name as `id` and values as your id , the one you are passing to route

Comment: @NileshsinhRathod have you try to `dd()` $this->id ?

Comment: @Jonjie yes already tried but get null

Comment: @NileshsinhRathod pass `$id` into the `rules()` method like so `rules($id)`

Comment: @NileshsinhRathod did you try adding a hidden field ?

Comment: @jaysingkar have you tried form request validation ?
see, i got request all field that is also passed from controller to formrequest but only id can't get.

Comment: @NileshsinhRathod Where did you use the `rules()` method?  because there's an other way to validate your form.

Comment: @NileshsinhRathod can you post your form ? As I know form Request is called before calling controller method. Reference => https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: @NileshsinhRathod to get the route parameter you can use `$id = $this->route('id');`

Comment: Can you show us your `route` for `update` method?

Comment: @NileshsinhRathod: Please give upvote if it's helpfull for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the id in the `Request` you can use the `route()` method. Keep in mind that use parameter name in `route('id')` which is used in your `routes.php` file!

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->route('id'); //or whatever it is named in the route
    return [
        'name' =>'required|unique:permissions,name,'.$id,
    ];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In form request you can get id by two way one is segment and another is route() function.

If you are using resource controller like

`Route::resource('permissions','PermissionController');` then `$this->route('permission');`

or

you are using custom route like `/permissions/{id}` then `$this->route('id');`

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->route('permission');
    return [
        'name' =>'required|unique:permissions,name,'.$id,
    ];
}
```

Or we can use segment also for getting id from route

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->segment(3);
    return [
        'name' =>'required|unique:permissions,name,'.$id,
    ];
}
```